# Emberjs filter() versus filterProperty()

Tags: ember.js

It seems like [filter()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filter) and [filterProperty()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterProperty) are quite similar, both are Enumerable functions returning a filtered array.

In what circumstances should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Update:** `filterProperty()` has been replaced by `filterBy()`. The usage is the same, see comment below.

`filterBy()` is a shortcut for `filter()` that lets you quickly filter an enumerable based on a specified property of the elements of the enumerable.  Use `filter()` if you need to do something more complicated or out-of-the-ordinary where you can't use `filterBy()`.

For example, assuming you had an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
  {firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
  {firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
]
```

And you wanted to have a computed property that uses filter the array to only include people with the `firstName == 'Luke'`:

**using `filter()`:**

```
filterComputed: function() {
  return this.get('content').filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
    return item.firstName == 'Luke';
  });
}.property('content.@each')
```

**using `filterBy()`:**

```
filterByComputed: function() {
  return this.get('content').filterBy('firstName', 'Luke');
}.property('content.@each')
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/81/edit)

Comment: NB `filterProperty` has been deprecated in favor of `filterBy`.  Same usage.  https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/882