# Filtering Emberjs Data by Attribute Properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I have an ember-cli 1.13.8 application where I would like to view the questions without answers.  Currently, I can filter searches based on attributes.  For example, I can search for the "content" of questions because that is an attribute on the object.

Models:

answer:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  content: DS.attr(),
  question: DS.belongsTo('question', { async: true })
});
```

questions:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  answers: DS.hasMany('answer', { async: true }),
});
```

For example, this works to query attributes of the current model (question):

```
model(query) {
 return this.store.findAll('question').then(function(questions) {
   return questions.filterBy("content", query);
 });
}
```

But I cannot filter based upon the properties (in this case length) of the attributes of the model.  I would like to filter based upon those questions which have no answers.

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('question').then(function(questions) {
    return questions.filter(function(item, index, enumberable) {
      return item.answers.length === 0;
    })
  });
}
```

Another attempt:

```
model() {
  this.store.findAll('question').filter('question', function(q) {
    return q.get('answers.length') === 0;
  })
}
```

I have consulted: 
    [Emberjs filter() versus filterProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924962/emberjs-filter-versus-filterproperty)

It seems that filterProperty() has been deprecated so examples such as: 
    http://www.kaspertidemann.com/how-to-filter-an-array-of-records-by-a-property-value-in-ember-js/  are not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the answers the answers relationship hasn't been loaded. The way I would do it is leave the route responsible for fetching the models and leaving the controller responsible for displaying the data.

In the route where you want to filter out questions with no answers:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('question').then( (questions) => {
    let promiseArray = questions.map( (question) => {
      return question.get('answer');
    })

    return Ember.RSVP.all(promiseArray);
  });
}
```

In the controller filter the models:

```
filteredModels: Ember.computed('model.[]', function() {
  return this.get('model').filter( (question) => {
     return question.get('answers.length') === 0;
  })
})
```

Comment: OK, I have tried to implement this solution but in the model it gets the error  that questions.get('answers') is undefined `return questions.get('answers').then ( (answers) => {`. Full error: `Error while processing route: unanwsered-questions Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Ah yeah forgot that questions is an array, updated the answer. Let me know if that works or not

Comment: OK, the model seems to go through now but in the controller it's throwing the same error but for `return question.get('answers.length') === 0;`.  I'm guessing this is because it's also an array?

Comment: It works after I actually just removed the model part sorting entirely and put it in the controller.  My model just returned the store. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, glad you were able to figure it out!